Audio problems using All in One HP PC
I'm trying to use an All in One HP PC and Reason 12 for music production. It has Intel Core i5-11500T (Rocket Lake-S) 1.5 GHz base frequency, up to 3.9 GHz Max Turbo Frequency, 12 MB L3 cache, 6 cores
35 W
Intel Core i7-11700T (Rocket Lake-S) 1.4 GHz base frequency, up to 4.6 GHz with Intel Turbo Boost Technology, 16 MB L3 cache, 8 cores
35 W
but I get frequent audio glitches , stutters and messages saying that the PC can't handle it.
The Latency Checker recommends changing the power setting but they are locked when I try to access them. Can anybody help

What sample rate and block size do you use in Reaper. Try 48000 and 512. It might help if you install Asio4all and use that driver.

It has an i5 and an i7 processor?  Are these the correct specs?
